# Output list of dependencies from POM.xml as text file

Tags: dependencies, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to export a list of all dependencies from my POM as *text file* during `mvn package` command execution.

The *text file* should contain following information about each dependency:

- lib name
- URL
- license type

I found the `maven-dependency-plugin` which I configured as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tree</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>tree</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>             
                <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/dep.txt</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It writes info about all dependencies, but I need **another format**.

Can this be achieved by any maven-plugin?

Comment: Can you [edit] and update your question with a sample output format?

Comment: Can you check the docs: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputType